Karma Test Fails with Chrome For Testing Browser
I am trying to execute the karma-jasmine test case by using Chrome For Testing browser.
If I execute the test with Installed Chrome browser then the test works fine, but if same test get executed with Chrome for Testing browser then it fails with error "Chrome has not captured in 60000 ms, killing".
If I have tried to execute the same test by passing the argument --no-sandbox to the Chrome for Testing browser then it execute successfully.
Why should I need to pass the --no-sandbox argument to execute the test with Chrome For Testing browser and not for installed chrome browser?
To replicate the issue follow below steps:

Create one directory in D drive e.g. karma-test

execute below command to setup karma
npm install karma --save-dev
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
npm install karma-junit-reporter --save-dev
npm install karma-mocha-reporter --save-dev
npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev

Download the chrome for testing browser from Chrome For Testing Dashboard
download the same chrome version which is installed into your system.

Extract the zip file into one folder / directory

Create karma.conf.js file as below .



// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Jul 09 2024 11:52:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../..',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'D:\\karma-test\\test.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress','junit','mocha'],
    junitReporter: {
           outputDir: 'jasmine/reports  ',
           //suite: moduleName
    },
    htmlReporter: {
           outputFile: 'jasmine/reports/test-results.html'
    },
    mochaReporter: {
           output: 'minimal'
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['chrome_testing'],
    customLaunchers: {
        chrome_testing:{
           base: "Chrome",
           chromeDataDir: "D:\\karma-test\\ChromeLogs\\logs-karma-installedChrome",
           //chromeDataDir: "D:\\karma-test\\ChromeLogs\\logs-karma-chromeForTesting",
           //chromeDataDir: "D:\\karma-test\\ChromeLogs\\logs-karma-installedChrome_noSandBox",
           //chromeDataDir: "D:\\karma-test\\ChromeLogs\\logs-karma-chromeForTesting_noSandBox",
           flags: [
                   "--enable-logging=stderr", 
                   "--v=1"
                   ,"--disable-infobars"
                   ,"--no-sandbox"
                  ]
        }       
    },
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}



Create sample jasmine test case. e.g. test.js.
Same file path needs to be added into files tag of karma.conf.js file.


 describe("suite name", function() {   
 beforeEach(function () {/*excute before each spec*/ })   
 it("contains spec with an
 expectation", function() {
     var browserAgent = navigator.userAgent;
     alert(browserAgent)
     alert("Hello World")
     //expect(true).toBe(true);   });  
 afterEach(function () { /*excute after each spec */ }) });



To execute the test with Chrome for Testing browser, set CHROME_BIN with the location of chrome.exe file.
e.g. If the chrome for testing browser zip file extracted into D:\\karma-test\chrome-win64 then set CHROME_BIN as below.



set CHROME_BIN=D:\\karma-test\chrome-win64\chrome\chrome.exe

After setting the CHROME_BIN, execute the command given in point 9.

To execute the test with installed chrome broswer. Open new command prompt -> go to karma-test directory -> execute the command given in point 9
Run the karma start or karma start <karma.conf.js file location>  command
To test the same test with --no-sandbox option uncomment/add it into flag tag in karma.conf.js

